# Gitlab clone showing an error: The project you were looking for could not be found

Tags: gitlab

I have installed the GitLab community edition on my centos 7 server. When I try to clone a repository it shows remote: The project you were looking for could not be found. Please help with this.

Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

- you have entered wrong credentials, try using ssh clone by adding your key in gitlab settings
- you do not have required authorization to access that repo, try accessing it via the browser first
- that repository don't exists, create it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a domain name resolution issue? A network issue?

Is there a software firewall installed that forbids the terminal from making network call?

## Possible network issues

My first hunch is a network issue or domain name resolution issue.

If you can connect at all to the repository, you should at least get a username and password challenge. If it was a credentials issue, you would at least get to that point.

Can you ping the URL? What if you use the IP address instead of the domain name? Just two things to try.

## Dig into the porcelin

GitLab does provide a porcelin rake command that allows you to check connectivity. You might want to give this a try as part of your troubleshooting routines.

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:tcp_check[ibm.com,80]
```